# LLVM fails to compile due to missing variables

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang

When I try to compile llvm with the following command from [here](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html), 
`cmake "Unix Make Files" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ~/llvm/1/llvm/`

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBCXXABI_LIBCXX_INCLUDES
   used as include directory in directory /home/salman/llvm/1/llvm/projects/libcxxabi/src
   used as include directory in directory /home/salman/llvm/1/llvm/projects/libcxxabi/src
   used as include directory in directory /home/salman/llvm/1/llvm/projects/libcxxabi/src
   used as include directory in directory /home/salman/llvm/1/llvm/projects/libcxxabi/src
```

Why is that? I have googled but cannot find a possible solution.

Comment: Where did you place `libcxx` and `libcxxabi` in the source tree? Also, The project advertises that its both Autotools/Make and Cmake based, but in reality, its pretty much Cmake based. Makefiles have a lot of trouble with LLBD, and don't work with LIBCXX and LIBCXXABI (speaking from experience).

Comment: Okay. Two things: 1) I just followed the tutorial here http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html . I don't know if it explicitly downloaded libvxx and libcxxabi. 2) I changed my `cmake` command to `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ~/llvm/1/llvm/` but it still didn't work.

Comment: *"I don't know if it explicitly downloaded libvxx and libcxxabi"* - no, you have to download it. It has its own download page at [libc++ C++ Standard Library](http://libcxx.llvm.org/). Maybe that's your issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem just now.

Look at [here](http://libcxx.llvm.org/):

> Check out libcxx and libcxxabi into llvm/projects

Make sure you check out **both** libcxx and libcxxabi in llvm/projects.

Comment: Whilst on a Gentoo platform, this worked, on my Dawrin platform, cross-compiling for linux, this did not fix it for me.  Not sure why yet.